# How to lock website download?

Tags: web

everyone.

I need to lock website for downloading via some windows tools and wget.
The site consists of js, html and php files.

I googled about security resource sharing, but it did not helpful for me.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as at the same time you need to have your website online available for everybody, this is not possible. If someone visits your site, the browser needs to access all files, in other words download them. You might be able to apply a few hacks to make it more difficult, but you can not prevent it completely.

If you want to restrict it to a defined audience, you can implement a login using for example HTTP Auth. How this can be achieved depends on your hosting. It might be doable using an .htaccess file in your web root or maybe through the admin interface of your hoster.

Your PHP file should be safe by the way, the above said applies to the public parts of your site (HTML/CSS/JavaScript/Images/...).